# Forget ORM, how do you design this in a relational database?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Lets say you want to create a database for a store which sells different products.

Products share certain attributes like name, description and price but every product has its own unique characteristics which doesn't share with other products. For example a book has "number of pages" but a computer has "storage capacity".

Lets say we will have comments on every product from users and we want to upload attachments for every product like images and videos.

How would you design this requirements in a relational database?

If more than one design is possible, can you please highlight why would you go for one and not the other?

Comment: Stay calm and use Table Inheritance

Comment: See also my answer regarding product catalogs particularly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231834/if-eav-is-evil-what-to-use-for-dynamic-values/17233204#17233204

Comment: thank you for your comments. Here is a good article I found: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server