# What is the advantage of using sp_rename to rename a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a sql table in sql server 2012 that I need to rename. I know in other database systems a way of executing this is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  RENAME TO new_table_name;
```

However, it seems SQL Server requires different syntax. From SQL Management Studio I renamed the table in the Design View and right clicked to Generate Change Script, and it produced the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'table_name', N'new_table_name', 'OBJECT' 
GO
ALTER TABLE new_table_name SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Is using [sp_rename](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) the best practice for renaming?

Also there is an additional line it generated to set the lock_esclation = table. Is this required?

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME ...` syntax isn't valid on any version of SQL Server I've ever worked with - it doesn't appear on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) either. From a quick google it appears to be postgresql syntax.

Comment: Indeed. Even [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337520.aspx) lists `sp_rename` in its example. (Also, re:LOCK_ENCAPSULATION, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703597/lock-escalation-whats-happening-here)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess the (slightly sarcastic) answer is the advantage to using `sp_rename` is that it is actually valid syntax on SQL Server, whereas the former is only valid on PostgreSQL ([documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)).

To see the valid options for `ALTER TABLE` - see [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Here is an example of using `Sp_rename`:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Sales.SalesTerritory', 'SalesTerr';
```

([Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) on `sp_rename`)