# Execute sp_rename SQL command using pypyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, t-sql, sqlalchemy, pypyodbc

Initially I had used the following command to rename SQL tables:

```
Q = """sp_rename {}, {}""".format(OLD_TABLE_NAME,NEW_TABLE NAME)
```

However, this caused an "Lock request time out period exceeded" error, which I believe was due to the lack of "commit" at the end of the query (although I am not confident on this).

So instead, I adopted a new query (adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162326/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-sp-rename-to-rename-a-sql-table)).

```
Q2 = """BEGIN TRANSACTION
    GO
    EXECUTE sp_rename N'{}', N'{}', 'OBJECT' 
    GO
    ALTER TABLE {} SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
    GO
    COMMIT""".format(OLD_TABLE_NAME,NEW_TABLE NAME,NEW_TABLE NAME)
```

However, I'm now getting a ProgrammingError saying "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."

Do I need to remove some parts of Q2 for the query to work? Or is some other part wrong?

Below are the two functions I use to connect to my SQL server:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pypyodbc as pp

server1 = {
        'drivername': 'mssql+pyodbc',
        'servername': 'SERVERNAME',
        #'port': '5432',
        'username': 'WebAccess',
        'password': ':|Ax-*6_6!5H',
        'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
        'trusted_connection': 'yes',  
        'legacy_schema_aliasing': False
        }

def getEngine(servername, database):
    DB = server1

    #Create connection to SQL database
    DB['database'] = database

    servername1 = servername.lower()

    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + DB['username'] + ':' + DB['password'] + '@' + DB['servername'] + '/' + DB['database'] + '?' + 'driver=' + DB['driver'])#, echo=True)

    return engine



def SQLcommand(query,servername,database):

    connection = pp.connect("""Driver={SQL Server};Server=""" + servername + """;Database=""" + database + """;uid=USERNAME;pwd=PASSWORD""")

    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute(query)

    connection.commit()

    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me based on the note in the SQLAlchemy Docs:

```
sql_stmt = f"""EXECUTE sp_rename '{table2}', '{table1}';"""            

with connection.begin() as conn:
     conn.execute(text(sql_stmt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright dude, you got a few problems here.

1. pypyodbc is something you should move away from.  That library was
   all the rage a while ago, but to my knowledge it's not getting many
   commits anymore, google is moving away from it, in my build we moved
   away from it for a number of reasons.  It was great while it lasted
   but I think its on the out.
2. You cannot use 'GO' in a query.  'GO' is not a tsql statement, its a sqlcmd command - thus it doesn't work with odbc.  'GO' essentially just breaks the code into batches, so to do this not using 'GO' you need to run multiple batches, something like:

   ```
   conn = engine.connect()
   tran = conn.transaction()
   conn.execute(f"EXECUTE sp_rename N'{OLD_TABLE_NAME}', N'{NEW_TABLE_NAME}', 'OBJECT'")
   conn.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {NEW_TABLE_NAME} SET LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE")
   tran.commit()
   ```

I'm sure there's more going on here as well, but hopefully this'll get you going.

Comment: The line `tran = conn.transaction()` causes the error `TypeError: transaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callable_'`

Comment: is your engine connected successfully?  After this line `conn = engine.connect()` try `conn.execute("SELECT 1")`   Does that line succeed or fail?

Comment: The output for that is `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy at 0xa987668>`

Comment: Is it because I'm using `sqlalchemy`? Is that not the library you were expecting? This link (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.transaction) suggests `conn.transaction()` does need a callable argument

Comment: Your output does not show the result of  "SELECT 1".  `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy at 0xa987668` is what happens when you reference a method or object without calling it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Should I do `print(conn.execute("SELECT 1"))` instead?

Comment: I think maybe you should look into some basic OOP programming principals.  You are getting a result, but it's in the form of an `object`.  You're seeing the `memory address` of that result `object` because you're printing the `reference` to the `object` instead of interacting with the `object` itself.  `objects` can only be interacted with via `methods` and `properties`.  I would suggest looking into these key terms.  That should get you to the finish line.  You're almost there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering how to solve the problem, I fixed [Jamie Marshall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310732/7914104) in order to adapt it to new `transaction` api:

```
conn = engine.connect()

def rename(cnxn):
    rename_query = f"EXECUTE sp_rename N'{OLD_TABLE_NAME}', N'{NEW_TABLE_NAME}', 'OBJECT'"
    cnxn.execute(rename_query)

conn.transaction(rename)
```